# Разделить строку на подстроки по символу

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, содержащая "теги":

```js
const str = '#first#second';
```

Как можно с помощью регулярных выражений разделить её на подстроки `first` и `second`?

Вот как у меня получилось без помощи regexp:

```js
const str = '#first#second'
const strMod = str.split('#');
strMod.shift();

console.log(strMod);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const str = '#first#second'
const parts = str.match(/[^#]+/g) || [];
console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const str = '#first#second';
console.log(str.match(/[^#]+/g));
```

Comment: А я видел `\w+`)))

Comment: @Qwertiy, хаха, главное, что понял, что можно и без :) Учиться никогда не поздно

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str = '#first#second'
const parts = str.split('#').filter(Boolean)
console.log(parts)
```

Comment: Варианты, пожалуйста, добавляйте в [существующий ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1250853/182013).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, а я считаю, что принципиально разные варианты должны быть в разных ответах.

Comment: Ничего в них нет принципиально разного.